# Upload progress for each file with formidable

Tags: node.js, upload, progress

I'm using Formidable module for uploading files.

With it's api we can get received and expected bytes of entire request and all uploaded files by listening the progress event.

Is there a way how to get upload progress for each file individually??

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious: Why do you care?

Comment: I care because it would be great for monitoring file server live.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at the way this popular [jquery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) does it

Comment: I know about this plugin and used it, but i just want to know if formidable can handle samehow this thing. No results after search and source check. Maybe http does not support this...